# Tiptap vue-2 extension throw error on construct

Tags: vue.js, tiptap

I have basic code from https://tiptap.dev/installation/vue2#3-create-a-new-component, but when component is loaded it throw error `vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElementNS' on 'Document': The qualified name provided ('[object HTMLDivElement]') contains the invalid name-start character '['."`

command executed: `npm i @tiptap/vue-2 @tiptap/starter-kit`

Element code:

```
<template>
    <editor-content :editor="editor" />
</template>

<script>
import { Editor, EditorContent } from '@tiptap/vue-3';
import StarterKit from '@tiptap/starter-kit';

export default {
    components: {
        EditorContent,
    },

    data() {
        return {
            editor: null,
        };
    },

    mounted() {
        this.editor = new Editor({
            content: `'<p>I’m running Tiptap with Vue.js. </p>'`,
            extensions: [StarterKit],
        });
    },

    beforeDestroy() {
        this.editor.destroy();
    },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you imported '`@tiptap/vue-3`'; while installed `npm i @tiptap/vue-2 @tiptap/starter-kit`
Both are not compatible, you need to install the right version your using, there u need to install tiptap/vue3